# golang is slow in Windows

Tags: go

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello world")
}
```

The command is `go run a.go`.
This code need 4~5s in windows.

Comment: the environment is  windows 64,  go 1.5rc1

Comment: `go run a.go` is slow because it compiles the code and then runs it. Try using `go build` or `go install` which will produce an executable binary (`a.exe`). Now try to run this .exe file, and you will see the result printed immediately.

Comment: No idea why this question has so many downvotes. Yes, it's a little unspecific, but `go run` is indeed very slow on Windows, even the newest versions. I think @Zan Lynx's second part of the answer is the reason for it.

Comment: If you have Git bash installed, just use that instead of Powershell or Command prompt and it will run almost instantly.

Comment: Antivirus programs with real-time protection are also potential candidates for slowing it down. That turned out to be the problem in my case.

Comment: I/O in Windows in general (and NTFS specifically) is just super slow, due many different reasons:
https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/873#issuecomment-425272829

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that `go run` compiles the code and then runs it. Go 1.5 is known to be much slower at compiling. (Read the release notes) The devs have converted it all to Go code but haven't optimized it for Go yet.

Also Go uses POSIX style disk and network operations. I don't believe anyone has optimized Go for completion ports and Windows asynch IO.

Comment: I suspect that the compile time impact for such a simple program between 1.4 and 1.5 is almost immeasurable. The impact is likely to do with the Windows command line, but without any further information (has the OP run 1.4? was it better?) these are just guesses.